# How do I setup a VPN server?

Tags: vpn

How can I create a VPN server that allow users to surf internet?  What is the requirements of the server and applications to setup on the server and users?  Configurations?

Answer (score 0):

I can't get you exactly what you're asking about. Internet is must required to connect to VPN.

If you want your network users to allow internet access you will need Proxy Server.

Answer (score 0):

it is very unclear what exactly you want... well if you really have intentions to get a VPN connection established and allow users to dial in from external network (internet enabled), there are plenty of linux based firewalls around.. my recommendation would be **Smoothwall** or **Untangle** which is easy to setup.